# vibrator not working in drag mode( Fatal Exception )

Tags: android, drag, vibration

I have a subclass(extends Activity) and all drag activity happen in this class, but in drag mode I can not use vibrator and I get Fatal exception:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
int idV = (Integer) v.getId();
if( idV==100)
{
MainActivity.BtDel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded);
Vibrator Vib = (Vibrator)     getSystemService(getApplicationContext().VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
Vib.vibrate(500);
return true;
}
.......
```

could you please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform a vibration you should do this:

```
import android.os.Vibrator;
```

then in on create

```
Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

then to vibrate

```
// Vibrate for 500 milliseconds 

v.vibrate(500);
```

**Include permission in AndroidManifest.xml file:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: I doesn't work. by this.context.... I get "context cannot be resolved or is not a field". please take into considration, that I am working on a subclass which it is not a main activity class. for example, the main activity class is "MainActivity.java" and MainActivity calls a subclass, which Processes drag and drop.

Comment: Ok, try to pass the context of the main class to the subclass